# Jersey body writer errors for java.lang.Boolean when deployed

Tags: java, jersey

I'm having trouble hunting down the the problem behind `SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Boolean, and Java type class java.lang.Boolean, and MIME media type application/json was not found`.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- using `jersey-bundle` instead of these individual packages
- POJOMappingFeature is already enabled
- Adding Jackson as a dependency

I'm unclear on what else I need to do.  This runs fine locally, so I'm unclear on why a dependency or two are not being packaged with the rest of the application.

**pom.xml**

```
    <jersey-version>1.17.1</jersey-version>
```

...

```
    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**Jersey Servlet**

```
//add jersey servlet support
ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new SpringServlet());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.company.product.resource");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.company.product.resource.ResponseCorsFilter");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
```

**My build process**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.company.product.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**The exception:**

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Boolean, and Java type class java.lang.Boolean, and MIME media type application/json was not found
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
```

**Code that generates error:**

```
@Path("/system")
public class SystemResource extends BaseResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/isOnline")
    public Boolean isOnline () {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}

@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class BaseResource {

}
```

I've verified that via the package log that jersey-json is being included in my jar.  One area of uncertainty for me is **which package/class actually provides the message body writer for Boolean?**

**Bounty** was added because this is preventing me from running in our production environment and we really need this resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're creating a one big `jar` file that contains your classes and all other dependencies. If this is correct (also the posted exception with only one provider leads me to this assumption) then make sure that all `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` (and `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`) files from your dependencies are combined together and not just replaced by ones from the latest jar that has been added to you uber-jar.

Make sure that your `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` file in the uber-jar (in `META-INF\services`) contains providers from this file that is present in `jersey-json`:

```
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$Wadl
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

The last one is especially important in your case since you're using Jackson as your JSON provider (by setting `POJOMappingFeature` to `true`).

#### EDIT 1

Many modules in Jersey 1.x uses `META-INF/services` mechanism to lookup for JAX-RS provides (i.e. `MessageBodyReader`s, ...). This means that you can find a service file in a jar (i.e. `jersey-json.jar!META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader`) in which are defined classes that Jersey runtime uses (i.e. to read/write entity from/to input/output). The issue with creating an uber-jar is that you also need to combine contents of same services (defined by the files with same name in `META-INF/services/` in your dependencies) into one file and bundle it into your executable jar (i.e. combine `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` from `jersey-core` and `jersey-json` and store it in `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader` in your jar).

In case of Jersey you can use `jersey-bundle` as mentioned elsewhere but make sure the `META-INF/services` files from `jersey-bundle` are in your resulting jar.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ to create this `jar` file.  Can you describe in a little more detail how I can "make sure that `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` are merged properly" ?

Comment: I've tried using `jersey-bundle`, and the exception only gets longer, still having the same issue http://pastebin.com/SHE5Dp51

Comment: Ok, this looks better. I forgot to mention that when you switch dependencies on Jersey modules to Jersey bundle you also need to explicitly define dependencies on Jackson as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19297865/290799 (+ add dependency on `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.12` as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try to include jackson also:

```
<jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please post your web.xml as well? And the code which produces the output

Comment: I don't have a web.xml, but I'll post the code for how I'm configuring Jersey

Comment: Config looks ok, could you please show the code which produces the output?

Comment: Try adding @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) above the method

Comment: Sorry, I should've included the BaseResource as well.

Comment: Try to return value as key-value pair. I don't think that just boolean value may be a valid JSON. If you wrap it into Map<String, Boolean>, e.g. {"status": true} it should look more like JSON.

Comment: It's not an issue with the Java syntax, it's something with the deployment of the application.  When I run it locally it runs great as is.  Something is not making into my final .jar which is causing the issue.

Comment: configuration looks fine, can you check adding jersey-bundle-1.8.jar probably it will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting of `META-INF/services` during jar creation seems to be the root cause (as described in the first answer). In my case adding:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

to the `<transformers>` config of the maven-shade-plugin in pom.xml has fixed the problem. Including a full `jersey-bundle` seems to be an overkill.

Comment: awesome.. I was struggling here for almost a week, it used to work fine in eclipse, but when i packed jar, it always went bad, and this is what I was missing. Thanks a done dude..

Answer (score 0):

No need to add 3rd-party libs because it has been included in jersey-json package.
The code seems not right, and it should be:

```
@Path("/system")
public class SystemResource extends BaseResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/isOnline")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Boolean isOnline () {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}

public class BaseResource {

}
```

Comment: The way I have them is actually correct.  The annotations are inherited by methods when put on a class, and a subclass when put on an extended class.