# Jersey body writer errors for java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm getting a trouble when I try to request a resource from a rest web service, I found the same problem in this page: [Jersey body writer errors for java.lang.Boolean when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283039/jersey-body-writer-errors-for-java-lang-boolean-when-deployed/19297865#19297865), but doesn't work for me, unfortunatelly. So, those are my codes:

**Code that generates error:**

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
  @Path("/isOnlineXml")
  public Boolean isOnlineXml(){
      return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.integration</param-value>
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>JAXRS-Rest</groupId>
<artifactId>JAXRS-Rest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>JAXRS-Rest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.company.product.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Finally, the exception:**

```
 A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Boolean, and Java type class java.lang.Boolean, and MIME media type application/xml was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/xml ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to encapsulate your Boolean value in a POJO that would be annotated with @XmlRootElement like:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class MyVO {

private Boolean booleanValue;

// getters and setters
}
```

that should be enough, on the other end you just retrieve the specific field of your VO bean.

If this still doesn't work last option would be mapping the field as a String and converting it if necessary when fetched via Javascript or other language.

Also you don't need to configure anything in your web.xml for JAX-RS, you can setup your services using a javax.ws.rs.core.Application:

```
package com.myapp.web.common.application;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyWebApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // register root resources
        classes.add(MyRESTService1.class);
        classes.add(MyRESTService2class);
        return classes;
    }      
}
```

Comment: I had tried  encapsulate the Boolean value, and it works, but I would like to know why is not possible return only the Boolean Object.

Comment: It's because there is no default message body writer for raw Boolean type on the out-of-the-box Jersey implementation, you need to encapsulate it on a class annotated with @XmlRootElement or else you can create your own custom message body writer. But I would go with the first option since it's simpler.